# How far from the Concorde's ground track was the sonic boom tolerable?

Tags: concorde, sonic-boom

How far away from the ground track did it drop to, say, the level.of heavy traffic? Or something else that people do not mind hearing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a sonic boom produced at 60,000' be heard on the ground?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17661/can-a-sonic-boom-produced-at-60-000-be-heard-on-the-ground)

Comment: @AadirajAnil no, it's about altitude, not ground track

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking about is called a "carpet", and sometimes, if I'm not mistaken, a "skirt".

Concorde was claimed to have a 20 km wide carpet (10 km either side), but in reality it was heard up to 40 km from the flight path.[Rogers] The secondary carpet was negligible (it's also delayed, if I recall correctly, by 15 minutes). Anyway, the best source is a public NASA report by Maglieri—here are two figures from it:

> [image: sonic boom carpet]

The N-wave estimation is 1 mile per 1,000' altitude, so the lower, the smaller the carpet. Feel free to use the report to write a more detailed answer.

Also, as I've [quoted here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/51974/73365), the pressure from Concorde's boom was "equivalent to the pressure one would feel when putting a hand out of the window of a car travelling at 30mph".

---

- Rogers, Peter H., and Domenic J. Maglieri. "Concorde booms and the mysterious east coast noises." *Acoust Today* 11.2 (2015): 34-40.
- Maglieri, Domenic J., et al. "Sonic boom: Six decades of research." (2014). https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20150006843